# Will naming all theorems and results I go over in a textbook aid in learning?

Tags: advice, learning

Something I have always thought since working with math textbooks is that it is very opaque to refer to a result like "Theorem 8.2" or "Proposition 1.10". When I took my intro to analysis course, I tried to mentally or explicitly assign every result a name to aid my learning and reinforce the concepts I just learned. Recently I learned that ProofWiki does the same, for example naming the results "Cardinality of Set of Surjections" or "Field is PID", even if the names get a bit cumbersome.  Is this a better approach to learning, or is it too cumbersome for results that are not summarized compactly?

Comment: Indeed, some technical lemmas then only can be named "technical Lemma 1, 2,3" and so on. So why not say immediately Lemma 1,2,3 and so on. So for learning, other things are more essential, I suppose.

Comment: To close voter: [tag:learning] is on-topic.

Comment: I think that it can be helpful for memory reasons. For example, it is a lemma that ideals $J$ containing a two-sided ideal $I$ in $R$ correspond bijectively to ideals in $R/I$. I would call this something like "the collapsing ideal lemma," which tells me the lemma is about behavior of ideals under quotients. That should be enough for me to remember any details. However, in writing and communication I find it much more helpful to just label by numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps you then do it.

You might want to name only the important theorems.

Some important theorems have names - use them.